# Cómo relacionar 3 tablas con Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos

Tengo una semana y aun no sé como solucionar este problema, soy nuevo en laravel así que tal vez hay una solución simple, pero aquí estoy.

Les explico:
Tengo 3 tablas:

- Persona (id, nombre, telefono, etc.)
- Poder(id, tipo_poder)-> el poder se refiere al documento legal que tiene una persona sobre una empresa, por ejemplo poder general, especial, etc.
- Empresa (id, nombre, telefono, etc).

Lo que necesito hacer es lo siguiente, este es mi formulario:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A como se puede ver, en el formulario se pueden agregar 2 personas con 2 poderes distintos o con el mismo tipo de poder y se deberían de guardar de forma simultánea, o puede ser únicamente 1 persona con un poder y la empresa.

Lo que necesito es ademas de agregar a la empresa que se agreguen las 2 personas con sus respectivo poderes y que queden relacionados tanto empresa, persona y poder, al mismo tiempo se debe de subir un documento adjunto que esté relacionado a la persona, tipo de poder y empresa.

He imaginado tener una tabla que relacione a todos:

- **Tabla_empresa_persona_poder**:(Id, empresa_id, persona_id, tpoder_id, docuemntoadjunto).

Como puedo hacer esa relación?, se que persona tiene muchos poderes y poderes tiene muchas personas, ahí tengo relaciones de muchos a muchos, pero luego debo tener una relación de 1 empresa tiene muchas personas y muchas personas pueden tener muchas empresas. Necesito su ayuda con las relaciones, si es posible en unificarlos en una sola tabla como la que mencioné (Tabla_empresa_persona_poder)

¿De qué forma lo podría hacer?.

Saludos y muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repasemos primero los requerimientos para aclararnos un poco.

A ver identifiquemos primero las entidades:

- **Empresas**
- **Gestores_representantes**
- **Poderes**

Ahora repasemos las relaciones:

- **Empresas**

  - Una empresa puede otorgar múltiples poderes.
- **Gestores_representantes**

  - Un gestor/representante puede ser asignado a múltiples poderes
- **Poderes**

  - Un poder pertenecen a una empresa
  - Un poder concreto solo puede ser asignado a un gestor/representante

Atributos mínimos de las entidades:

- Empresas

  - id
  - nombre
- Gestores_representantes

  - id
  - nombre
- Poderes

  - id
  - id_empresa
  - id_gestor_representante
  - archivo

---

Yo veo solo 2 relaciones 1:N con poderes

1 empresa : N poderes

1 gestor_representante : N poderes

---

De esta forma sería fácil obtener:

- Todos los poderes, junto a sus empresas y gestores
- Todas las empresas, junto a sus poderes y gestores
- Todos los gestores, junto a sus poderes y empresas

Comment: Muchas gracias!!